# Python Math module subtleties

Tags: python, forms, math, module

I've been experimenting with the standard python math module and have come across some subtle difficulties. For example, I'm noticing the following behavior concerning indeterminate forms:

```
0**0

>>> 1

def inf():
    return 1e900
    # Will return inf

inf()**inf()

>>> inf
```

And other anomalies of the sort. I'm writing a calculator, and I'd like to have it be mathematically accurate. Is there something I can do about this? Or, is there some way to circumvent this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to know how floating point numbers work: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Never knew that Python says 0^0 == 1 >.<

Comment: What exactly do you not like about these results?

Comment: @Corbin: I also just learnt this behaviuor.It is mentioned in [math.pow](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.pow) docs.

Comment: If 0**0 is to be defined at all, it _should_ be 1.

Comment: @sth I'm truly all for designing a calculator that observes the formality of mathematics. 0^0 = 1 is contradictory, disregarding convention. See MDT's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your first example. `0**0` is often defined to be 1.

The second example is all to do with precision of doubles. `1E900` exceeds the maximum positive value of a (most likely 64-bit) double. If you want doubles outside of that range, you'll have to look into libraries. Fortunately Python has one built-in: [the decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

For example:

```
from decimal import Decimal
d = Decimal('1E900')
f = d + d
print(f)
>>> 2E900
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the decimal module, that should come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wolfram (quoting Knuth) while 0**0 is indeterminate, it's sometimes given as 1. This is because holding the statement 'x**0 = 1' to be true in all cases is in some cases useful. Even more interestingly Python will consider NaN**0 to be 1 as well.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Power.html

In the case of infinity**infinity, you're not really dealing with the mathematical concept of infinity here (where that would be undefined), but rather a number that's too large and has overflowed. As such all that statement is saying is that a number that's huge to the power of another number that's huge is still a number that's huge.

Edit: I do not think it is possible to overload a built in type (such as float) in Python so overloading the float.__pow__(x,y) operator directly. What you could possibly do is define your own version of float.

```
class myfloat(float):
    def __pow__(x,y):
        if(x==y==0):
            return 'NaN'
        else:
            return float.__pow__(x,y)

m = myfloat(0)
m**0
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for though.

Comment: Thanks MDT. Is there any way around this? For example, for my calculator, can I somehow tell the Interpreter if an input of `0**0` (not necessarily as a string) is encountered, return `'Indeterminate form.'`?

Answer (score 1):

Well returning NaN for `0**0` is almost always useless and lots of algorithms avoid special cases if we assume `0**0 == 1`. So while it may not be mathematically perfect - we're talking about IEEE-754 here, mathematical exactness is really the least of our problems [1]

But if you want to change it, that's rather simple. The following works as expected in Python 3.2:

```
def my_pow(x, y):
    if y == 0: return 'NaN'
    return float.__pow__(float(x), y)

pow = my_pow
```

[1] The following code can theoretically execute the if branch with x86 CPUs (well at least in C and co):

```
float x = sqrt(y);
if (x != sqrt(y)) printf("Surprise, surprise!\n");
```

Comment: Out of interest does this mean 0**0 will return 'NaN' or just pow(0,0)?

(0**0 still returns 1 in 2.7 but I don't have 3.2 to test it in)

Comment: @MDT Completely forgot that python enabled the `**` operator, sadly that doesn't work with `**` under python3 either :( I just disassembled it and `**` uses the `BINARY_POWER` opcode so there's no way we can change it without changing c code and recompiling the interpreter sadly